# remove role on unreact can't get member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is a basic code that gives you a role when you react to a certain message with a specific emoji, or remove the role when you unreact

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('bot is online')

#this works
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  message_id = payload.message_id
  if message_id == 869153559042748446:
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

    if payload.emoji.name == '''1️⃣''':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=868532817984901151)
    else:
      print('''else''')
      role = None

  if role is not None:
    member = payload.member
    if member is not None:
      await member.add_roles(role)
      print('''gave role {} to {}'''.format(role, member))
    else:
      print('''member not found''')
  else:
    print ('''role not found''')

#This is an exact copy of **on_raw_reaction_add** but
#**await member.add_roles(role)** changed to *await member.remove_roles(role)*
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
  message_id = payload.message_id
  if message_id == 869153559042748446:
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

    if payload.emoji.name == '''1️⃣''':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=868532817984901151)
    else:
      print('''else''')
      role = None

  if role is not None:
    member = payload.member
    if member is not None:
      await member.remove_roles(role)
      print('''gave role {} to {}'''.format(role, member))
    else:
      print('''member not found''') #This always prints
  else:
    print ('''role not found''')


bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

**on_raw_reaction_add** works as intended,
but when it comes to **on_raw_reaction_remove** it can't find **member** even tho it's exact copy of **on_raw_reaction_add**.

PRESENCE INTENT & SERVER MEMBERS INTENT are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `member` attribute on payload only works if a reaction is added ([Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.member))

> The member who added the reaction. Only available if event_type is REACTION_ADD and the reaction is inside a guild.

You can try to get it with `discord.utils` or `guild.get_member()`

Example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    ...
    # discord.utils.get()
    member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

    # guild.get_member()
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)

    ...
```